# Moving to named anchor after jquery/javascript processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

How do move focus to a different section (named anchor) on the same page after doing some jquery processing.

Function ABC() does some processing and afterwards, I need to move the user to a section on the same page (further down the page).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the code below to scroll the screen to a `<div id="navigation">`.  Just change the selector to match the element you want to scroll to.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#navigation').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Comment: I have an app embedded in youtube channel.I cannot control the screen page of youtube to scroll down to certain section in my app since $(html,body) gives some else body in which my app area div doesnt exist. Thereby the offset is returned null. Can I make the screen page scroll of youtube scroll to certain section of my app.This app is under a brand page channel of a youtube. eg http://www.youtube.com/user/Clipstervideo

Answer (score 1):

`location.href=location.href.replace(/#.+/,'')++'#namedanchor'` or

```
document.getElementById('#namedanchor').scrollIntoView(true)
```

The first appends the hash to the address URL

Comment: Thank you kennebec, your first solution works very well for asp.net with postback :)